# How much information should a docstring contain

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

I have function that takes as arguments a number of classes of average complexity.

When writing docstring for that function, I'm running into a series of questions: Should I describe (besides what the function is doing) those classes too, or can I assume that the reader will dig up the class definition?  Or should I point to where the classes are defined? What is the best practice?

Comment: Does your function take classes (which are first class objects in Python) as arguments, or does it take instances of classes as arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any modern IDE should allow the reader to jump to the definition of referenced classes at a single mouse click. There is no point in repeating this information (denormalization of data is sometimes a good idea, but not in software documentation).

Therefore, when a `StringDistance` method takes `String`s as arguments, you should certainly not describe what a String is; when a `LoanRiskCalculator` uses `Loan`s, you probably shouldn't describe `Loan`s either. That information is better placed within the `Loan` class.

The edge case is when the argument classes are dedicated helper classes that are more or less useful *only* for use with this method or this class. Then it can be a good idea to describe them together with the algorithm that they serve. A `StringDistance` method that uses `ReverseTrieLookupTable`s to communicate with associated other methods might pull the documentation of thease specilized helpers into its own docstring, or at least into the class docstring.

Answer (score 3):

The specific term *docstring* you are using indicates that you are using Python. (Or Cobra, but the latter one is far less likely.)

Note that in Python, what is relevant is the *protocol*, and *not* the class of your parameters. (This is called *duck typing*, or really just OO.) So, you shouldn't document the class *at all* neither by reference nor by copy. The definition of those classes is completely irrelevant.

What *is* relevant, is what *protocol* your function expects from its parameters. You should document that. Also, you should document what protocol your function guarantees for its return value.

Comment: +1, but I don't understand what exactly you mean by "protocol" (the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing does not contain any mention of this). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The term *protocol* is much older than the term *duck typing*. It is a general OO term. It means the set of messages an objects understands and how it responds to them.

Comment: @user7088941 I think Jörg is trying to say that when you design a function you don't always know exactly what will be passed to you as a parameter (what class, what implementation) only how you'll use it (protocol, duck typing). Therefore your documentation should reflect that reality, not make a bunch of assumptions.

Comment: For example, if you write a `sum` function, you don't care that your parameter is a `list` of `int`s. What you *do* care about is that your parameter conforms to the iterable protocol and that its elements have an `__add__` method that returns something that also has an `__add__` method. That's it. That way, you can sum lists of integers but also sets of strings or stacks of lists.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand now what you mean, thank you! But are you really sure that it is a good idea to write docstrings solely by having the protocol in mind? Because the docstrings will end up become pretty useless in that case, since they will be much too cryptic/abstract: Imagine I'm doing a few string operations inside a function, taking two arguments that are arrays of strings as input. I want to write a docstring for this function. [...]

Comment: [...] Now I will have some internal structure in these inputs (meaning, structure additional to the "protocol signature"), since the way this function is used in my program makes it impossible to call it with random inputs. If I'm solely referring the protocol, I'm completely neglecting the narrow space that the inputs that will actually occur, and I will only describe the vast space of all "protocol-preserving" inputs, making my docstring impractical, right?